# How DataDome Captcha and bad ip protection can be bypassed?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, captcha

I am working with undetected_chromedriver in Selenium

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("--window-size=920,1080")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
```

This site keeps blocking my ip when scraping data from this site and no effect by using proxy also.
[image]
I tried using proxy + some random header function but is of no use.